# Allowing Javascript expressions in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My problem is this: I'm trying to run javascript in certain expression in my report

This is what I have in my textbox:

```
    =Code.test()
```

In my report properties I got the following code:

```
 Function test()  AS String

   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("< script language='javascript' >alert('This is a test');< /script >") 

return ""

 End Function
```

When trying to deploy my reportserver I get the following error:

```
 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox4.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers
```

I read on the following link that I have to give fulltrust to the assembly : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02f3d049-fc25-44c0-b03a-34820f75bfa7/couldnt-able-to-use-systemwebhttpcontextcurrentrequesturlabsoluteuri-in-c

Now, I  assumed ( could be wrong) that the assembly I have to give fulltrust value to is this one: AspNetHostingPermission

So I added this to rssrvpolicy.config and rsmgrpolic.config

```
   <CodeGroup 
                    class="FirstMatchCodeGroup" 
                    version="1" 
                    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
                    Description="This code group grants MyComputer code Execution permission. ">
                        <IMembershipCondition 
                            class="AspNetHostingPermission"
                            version="1"
                            Zone="MyComputer" />

                 </CodeGroup>
```

However, when restarting my report server and trying to access localhost/reportserver I get this error:

> library!DefaultDomain!3b38!02/14/2017-11:20:34:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException:
>   Failed to create HTTP Runtime,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException:
>   An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for
>   application domain ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0.  --->
>   System.Web.HttpException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ReportingServicesWebServer, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG)) (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\web.config
>   line 14) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'ReportingServicesWebServer,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) (C:\Program    Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\web.config
>   line 14) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'ReportingServicesWebServer, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) File name: 'ReportingServicesWebServer,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: Element must be a  element. ---> System.ArgumentException: The
>   type does not implement IMembershipCondition

I'm assuming it's because of  where I'm trying to add the codeGroup? I'm not very familiar with the file structure of those 2 configurations file. If someone more knowledgeable could point me in the right direction it would be awesome!

As a side note: I  changed the other codegroup to Permission FullTrust just to see if it would change something ( without my extra piece of xml-code on top) but it didn't enable the javascript code more, it still gave me #error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the javascript in your report?

Comment: RIght now it's just a basic test, Just trying to make a pop up window appear with alert. However,  in the future  I'm hoping to be able to take a file I/O to read a file to take the JS from there ( we have  multiple report , ~ 250  and I'd like 1 js file for all the reports for a question of modularity if ever I need to change something)

Comment: You still haven't said what you want to achieve with the javascript besides load more javascript...

Comment: Oh , basically display a picture  / create a new div in my html page

Comment: Within the report?  I would recommend you either load the picture from the built in functionality in your report or display your report within an iframe that you format around.  Look into [SSRS URL parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) on how to seamlessly display reports in a webpage and you can have complete HTML/CSS/JS control on the rest of the page.

Comment: I can't load the picture from the report,  we pick the picture from a certain place and every costumer has a different one. So we can't go in and change manually 250 pictures for every costumer  unfortunately, hence why I'm trying to do it with JS. Howeer I'll look into iframe

Comment: You can tell the report to [load a picture from an external source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220527.aspx), such as a webserver.  If you know which picture you need to load from other info within the report and you have a semi sensible file structure, you can load the image at run time and change as required using either your original dataset or expressions.

Comment: However, just by curiosity because I'd like to know what's happening, if I wanted to load custom code, would you know how to structure the config files ?